# $PWD vs. Get-Location in powershell or pwsh?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Powershell has [`$PWD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#pwd) and also [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-7.3), both effectively returning the current "shell location" <sub>(as opposed to `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory`)</sub>.

`$PWD`is documented as:

> Contains a path object that represents the full path of the current
> directory location for the current PowerShell runspace.

And `Get-Location`is documented as:

> gets an object that represents the current directory, much like the print working directory (pwd) command.

*Neither* doc page mentions the other option.

So is there any difference in the value they produce? Possibly with multiple runspaces?

Comment: The former is a variable, the latter a cmdlet

Comment: `$pwd` is pretty much `Get-Location` with no paramaters, both output `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation` but the cmdlet allows to get your location in different providers, psdrives and stacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Santiago answered this in the comments:

> `$pwd` is pretty much `Get-Location` with no parameters, both output
> `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation` but *[the cmdlet allows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location) to
> get your location in different providers, psdrives and stacks*